# Django-OAuth-Twitter error in Google App Engine 1.4.0 -- Unexpected keyword arguments: next_count, prefetch_count, offset

Tags: django, google-app-engine, twitter, django-nonrel

Google recently updated their appengine sdk to 1.4.0, and at the same time I've started seeing exceptions both on my devbox and in production.  Here's the trace:

```
Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 101, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/django_oauth_twitter/views.py", line 159, in callback
    user = self._authenticate(userinfo=userinfo)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/django_oauth_twitter/views.py", line 239, in _authenticate
    user = TwitterUser.objects.get(twitter_id=userinfo.id).user
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/django/db/models/query.py", line 79, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/django/db/models/query.py", line 267, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/base/data/home/apps/ezcrd2/10.346707310382875890/common-apps/djangoappengine/db/compiler.py", line 96, in results_iter
    next_count=75)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 1304, in Run
    config = _Rpc2Config(_GetConfigFromKwargs(kwargs))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 169, in _GetConfigFromKwargs
    'Unexpected keyword arguments: %s' % ', '.join(args_diff))
DatabaseError: Unexpected keyword arguments: next_count, prefetch_count, offset
```

I'm guessing the breakage is likely related to this appengine change, but not sure how to fix it: https://gist.github.com/717904

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the problem was evidently that I was using an old version of django-nonrel.  It had nothing to do with django-oauth-twitter